# Unable to export plotly image to png with Kaleido

Tags: python, version-control, plotly, kaleido

Here's my code:

```
fig = px.pie(df.groupby('TypeObject').count(), 
             values='ID',
             names=df.groupby('TypeObject').count().index, 
             color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.YlGnBu)
fig.show()

fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")
```

I'm getting this Error:

```
 ResourceWarning:

unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=3>


ValueError: --plotlyjs argument is not a valid URL or file path:
```

I get the same error using

```
fig.show('png')
```

It all worked for me before, but I've updated python version and everything if falling apart

What can I do tho fix this?

I've already tried

```
pip install --upgrade "kaleido==0.1.*"
```

And

```
import plotly.io as pio
                                                                         
pio.kaleido.scope.chromium_args += ("--single-process",)
```

And setting version  plotly==5.3.1

And adding import kaleido  before plotly

I've also tried orca and got some issues there too

Comment: Please refer to the plotly community for a [response](https://community.plotly.com/t/static-image-export-hangs-using-kaleido/61519/3). I am on Windows 11 and can output images with kaleido 0.1.0.post1.

Comment: I downgraded to python 3.10 but still keep getting the same error

Comment: Forgot to add, plotly is the latest version, 5.15.0. Is your OS Windows?

Comment: If you have no problem with increasing the version of plotly, why don't you try the latest version?

Comment: Upgraded plotly to the latest version, still the same problem. I'm running on Windows 10 Pro